# How to reverse draw order of model bones in XNA 4.0?

Tags: model, draw, transparent, xna-4.0

When I draw model with transparent textures I got this :

[bad tree](http://s9.postimage.org/nl7hzpltr/tree.png)

I think that it is caused by bad order of drawing. Unfortunately I'm not modeler, I have the model from turbosquid and it should look like this :
[good tree](http://preview.turbosquid.com/Preview/2012/06/07__13_39_49/Treeingame.jpg1af0fa83-0179-4d41-9f6d-d09592ca1f31Large.jpg)

FBX model consist one mash with several bones. Is it possible to draw bones in reverse order in XNA4? (I'm using basic effect, not own shaders)

Or can I reverse order of bones in program? Something like this :

```
    m.Bones = m.Bones.Reverse();
```

Answer (score 0):

No. Bones are not "drawn". Bones provide transformations to vertices in the mesh allowing (for example) the tree to bend. Each vertex takes transformation values from one or more bones. Then the mesh (made up of triangles made up of those vertices) is drawn.

Changing the draw order will only work for certain camera orientations. Basically you always want each triangle in your model to be drawn from back to front. Often you can't do this for performance reasons - particularly for individual triangles within a single model.

There is a way around this: the **depth buffer** allows you to sort individual pixels as they are drawn. If a pixel is "in front" of what was previously drawn - it replaces the pixel on the screen and becomes the new "front". If it is behind, it simply doesn't get drawn.

The problem that arises here is that your model contains transparency. If a transparent pixel gets drawn while the depth buffer is in use, it will "hide" the pixels that should be drawn "underneath" it (when, *visually speaking*, it shouldn't hide anything, as it is transparent).

The solution to that problem is to use **alpha testing**. When enabled, transparent pixels will never be drawn - and thus never mess up your depth buffer.

To do this you need to use `AlphaTestEffect` with `DepthStencilState.Default`.